# Buying game collection that contains game that I own Steam

Tags: steam

Let's say I buy a game. And after a few months, the bundle that contains the game (e.g. all games from specific publisher or developer or franchise) go on sale and I wish to buy that bundle. What happens to that game? is it removed from the bundle and I not pay for it? Do I get charged twice? Do I get the game as a gift?

Comment: I'm pretty sure since you already own the game you'll receive it as a gift in your inventory if you a purchase a bundle that contains the same game.

Comment: well yeah, I made the same assumption but still I would prefer a concrete and documented answer :)

Comment: This varies from bundle to bundle.  Steam will usually mark in the cart which ones you will not receive duplicates of, when buying from steam.  Grouped game keys from humble bundle typically do not provide extra copies.

Comment: I am asking for purchase from within steam only

Comment: Starting a month or two ago, there are now two different types of bundles on Steam.  The older style bundles may or may not give you a giftable copy of the games you already have.  The newer style simply lowers the price

Comment: Borderlands 2 has both types of bundles.  [First type](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/46441/). [Second type](http://store.steampowered.com/bundle/257/). Note that you CANNOT gift the second type of bundle to other people. Also note that the second bundle also has the Pre-Sequel in it but is still cheaper than the first bundle.

Comment: @Powerlord Is there a way to tell which bundles allow you to gift spare-copies and which do not?

Comment: Maybe make these comments into a real answer?

Comment: According to RPS steam has also added a way for the developers to set dynamic pricings to the bundle so that if you already own 1 of the games the price will go down: https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2016/03/05/steam-bundle-prices/

Comment: Nop. Not a duplicate. This deals with bundles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Steam's page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4502-TPJL-2656), you will receive an extra copy meeting the following conditions:

> Extra copies will only be issued as a special promotion in the
>   following specific cases:
>
> 1. Users who own “Half-Life 2” and go on to purchase “The Orange Box” will receive an extra copy of “Half-Life 2”.
> 2. Users who own “Half-Life 2: Episode One” and then go on to purchase the “The Orange Box” will receive an extra copy of “Half-Life
>      2: Episode One”.
> 3. Users who own "Dawn of War II"and then go on to purchase "Dawn of War II Gold Edition" will receive an extra copy of "Dawn of War II"
> 4. Users who purchase the available four packs for specific Steam titles will receive three extra copies of that title to gift to
>      friends.
> 5. Extra copies may apply as a part of some limited time promotions. In that case, information on what will be included with your purchase
>      will be listed on the storefront's transaction page.
>
> These special promotions will allow you to send a gift pass for your
>   extra copy to a friend who does not already own the game. These
>   promotion do not apply to any games other than those specifically
>   listed.

Steam will normally tell you if you will get an extra copy (or if you won't) when the bundle is in the cart - this is the surest way to know before you buy it.